# Web browser integration

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, integration, screenshot

I need to create a software solution, that will use browser capabilities to perform some tasks.

More specific, i will need to do the following:

- Load some page (by URL)
- Analyse generated content (DOM), i need to access dynamically generated page, not just initial HTML document
- Do a screenshot of some region of the page and save it to a file

What is the best way to do this?

What existing browser would allow me to do this and how exactly? Generally i prefer Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/index.html)
It will allow you to load a webpage, then capture any area and save it to a file.
It allow also to play with DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Google Chrome extension to do that.

1.In the extension, you can load page or add listener to observer the tab activities.

2.You can execute scripts on the page loaded,even use jQuery to Analyse the dom.

3.You can use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab function to take a screenshot,And then use canvas to handle the screenshot image.

more details about Chrome extension develop:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

Comment: Thanks, i will definitely consider it.